# Multiple word documents in dock

Tags: ms-office, dock

I have had Microsoft Word installed on my mac for years, and it used to be that I could see a list of opened documents just by right-clicking the word icon in the dock. But some time ago, it seems that this functionality disappeared.

Does anyone know why? And is there a way to make it work again?

Answer (score 1):

This continues to work for me, as long as Word is currently running - 2011 or 2016 editions.